# Using CMakes qt_wrap_ui command

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm currently trying to change the build system used for a QT project from Visual Studio to CMake and I'm having trouble figuring out the correct usage of the qt_wrap_ui command. Currently, I'm using it like this:

```
macro(addQtForProject argLibraryName argSourceList)

    ...

    qt_wrap_ui(${argLibraryName} ${argSourceList} ${argSourceList} ${varUiList})

endmacro()
```

As I handle the source and headers as a single list, I of course want the generated files to end up in the same list. varUiList contains the four .ui files used by the project.

When using CMakes visual studio 2005 generator with this macro, it adds four .h files, one for each .ui file, to the Visual Studio project file but the files themselves does to seem to exist at all so I must be doing something wrong. CMakes [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aqt_wrap_ui) is unfortunatly fairly sparse on this subject. This has been tested with CMake 2.8.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the more recent [`FindQt4` module](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aFindQt4) which has much more documentation.

Specifically, it provides the `QT4_WRAP_UI` macro:

> `QT4_WRAP_UI(outfiles inputfile ... OPTIONS ...)`
>           create code from a list of Qt designer ui files.
>           Options may be given to uic, such as those found
>           when executing "uic -help"